# Why does my for loop only check the last item?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-requests, grequests

I've built a async'ed program thats going to check if a element exists on multiple paths of a website.
The program has a base url, that will get different paths of the domain to check, which are located in a json file (name.json).
If the element I'm looking for exists the program should print out "1". But I've quickly realised that it only chooses to check the last item in the json list.

```
import json
import grequests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

idlist = json.loads(open('name.json').read())

baseurl = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/'

for uid in idlist:
    fullurl = baseurl + uid

rs = (grequests.get(fullurl) for uid in idlist)
resp = grequests.map(rs)

for r in resp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    if soup.find('span', class_='actual_persona_name'):
        print('1')

    else:
        print('2')
```

The json file just consist of a random array to test the program.

```
["xyz", 
"sdasda9229", 
"sdasda923229", 
"sda", 
"sda",
"sda",
"sd2",
"aaaaaa",
"aaaaaaaaa",
"aa2092425",
"aaaa23917"]
```

Answer (score 1):

After appending the id to the base url, it's not getting stored. You have to store it and pass the complete urls while constructing the `get` request

```
complete_urls = []

for uid in idlist:
    fullurl = baseurl + uid
    complete_urls.append(fullurl)

rs = (grequests.get(fullurl) for fullurl in complete_urls)
```